# git archive : how to ignore pathspec during archive?

Tags: git, git-archive

I am trying to create an archive of the files in the latest 3 commits using the following command.

```
git archive -o archive.zip $(git diff --name-only HEAD~3)
```

But in the last commit i deleted a few files, this is showing in the `diff` output. so i am getting this error:

```
fatal: pathspec 'public/uploads/5839529ba9381.png' did not match any files
```

How do i ignore the files that are deleted in a commit during git archive? I've tried the `--ignore-unmatch` argument but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation, Heres something that works.

```
tar vczf archive.tar.gz --ignore-failed-read `git diff --name-only hash1 hash2`
```

I too was looking for, **git archive ignore deleted files**. As I wanted to create an archive of files that were added/modified between two branches/tag/hash etc.

The solution is to use `tar` instead of git archive, and pass the output of `git diff` in the same manner, only benefit here is that you can actually ignore missing files (*deleted between commits*) using the flag `--ignore-failed-read`. Also one thing to note is that this flag should come after the archive-file name.

Comment: I wonder if `--ignore-failed-read` could ignore too much, e. g. actual read error due to a file defect or a sharing violation?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, `git archive` is used to backup status of a certain time point, not fit to backup modifications of time line, i.e, you can not save an action of `delete files` by `git archive`.

If you want to backup latest 3 commits, you can use `git bundle` command.

```
git bundle create last_three_commit.bundle HEAD~3..HEAD
```

or

```
git bundle create last_three_commit.bundle -3 HEAD
```

Please run `git bundle --help` for more details.

Comment: the command is not working, are there two dots?, should there be spaces?

Comment: @bazi, sorry, i missed the bundle filename in command line. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @bazi, .bundle  is a file format defined by git to achieve objects and refs, I think you can not specify zip format for it.

Comment: is there any way to get zip file including project files? not objects or refs

Comment: @bazi yup there is, look at my answer. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me:

```
git archive -o archive.zip $(git diff --name-only --no-renames --diff-filter=a hash1..hash2)
```

Where *hash1* is the newer commit hash and *hash2* is for the older commit.

The *--no-renames* gets the new names for renamed files, not the original names.